# Python: Fail to request html from https site

Tags: python-3.x, https

I am trying to request the html data from the web site as shown below, but it prompts following error:

`'Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')"`

I have tried to add the certificate as well, but it also prompts following error:

> Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'no certificate or crl found')]

The certificate is exported from Chrome.

Python Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ='https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/restaurants/type/%E5%BF%AB%E9%A4%90%E5%BA%97?page=1'

html=requests.get(url, verify=False)
#html=requests.get(url, verify="/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2.cer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

First of all, I didn't reproduce your environment the same way, and I tried to access the site from my PC, but it didn't work so well, so I added a `user-agent` to the header and it worked fine.

But I don't know if it will work on your PC.

```
import requests
url ='https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/restaurants/type/%E5%BF%AB%E9%A4%90%E5%BA%97?page=1'

headers = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
}
html=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(html.text)
```